Why do I get an error when migrating the module about the absence of the path_to_storage module?
Why do I get an error when migrating the module about the absence of the path_to_storage module? there is no word about this module on google. I wanted to add a django-ckeditor-5 editor and was guided by this article - enter link description here. Below I am sending my actions and what errors I received. What did I do wrong?
$ pip install django-ckeditor-5==0.2.12
$ cat Project1/settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import os
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'portfolio',
    #'ckeditor', 
    #'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django_ckeditor_5',
]
...
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
#MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
customColorPalette = [
        {
            'color': 'hsl(4, 90%, 58%)',
            'label': 'Red'
        },
        {
            'color': 'hsl(340, 82%, 52%)',
            'label': 'Pink'
        },
        {
            'color': 'hsl(291, 64%, 42%)',
            'label': 'Purple'
        },
        {
            'color': 'hsl(262, 52%, 47%)',
            'label': 'Deep Purple'
        },
        {
            'color': 'hsl(231, 48%, 48%)',
            'label': 'Indigo'
        },
        {
            'color': 'hsl(207, 90%, 54%)',
            'label': 'Blue'
        },
    ]
CKEDITOR_5_CUSTOM_CSS = 'path_to.css' # optional
CKEDITOR_5_FILE_STORAGE = "path_to_storage.CustomStorage" # optional
CKEDITOR_5_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link',
                    'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'imageUpload', ],

    },
    'extends': {
        'blockToolbar': [
            'paragraph', 'heading1', 'heading2', 'heading3',
            '|',
            'bulletedList', 'numberedList',
            '|',
            'blockQuote',
        ],
        'toolbar': ['heading', '|', 'outdent', 'indent', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'underline', 'strikethrough',
        'code','subscript', 'superscript', 'highlight', '|', 'codeBlock', 'sourceEditing', 'insertImage',
                    'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',  'blockQuote', 'imageUpload', '|',
                    'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', 'mediaEmbed', 'removeFormat',
                    'insertTable',],
        'image': {
            'toolbar': ['imageTextAlternative', '|', 'imageStyle:alignLeft',
                        'imageStyle:alignRight', 'imageStyle:alignCenter', 'imageStyle:side',  '|'],
            'styles': [
                'full',
                'side',
                'alignLeft',
                'alignRight',
                'alignCenter',
            ]

        },
        'table': {
            'contentToolbar': [ 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells',
            'tableProperties', 'tableCellProperties' ],
            'tableProperties': {
                'borderColors': customColorPalette,
                'backgroundColors': customColorPalette
            },
            'tableCellProperties': {
                'borderColors': customColorPalette,
                'backgroundColors': customColorPalette
            }
        },
        'heading' : {
            'options': [
                { 'model': 'paragraph', 'title': 'Paragraph', 'class': 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
                { 'model': 'heading1', 'view': 'h1', 'title': 'Heading 1', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading1' },
                { 'model': 'heading2', 'view': 'h2', 'title': 'Heading 2', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading2' },
                { 'model': 'heading3', 'view': 'h3', 'title': 'Heading 3', 'class': 'ck-heading_heading3' }
            ]
        }
    },
    'list': {
        'properties': {
            'styles': 'true',
            'startIndex': 'true',
            'reversed': 'true',
        }
    }
}
$ cat Project1/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from portfolio import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('', include('portfolio.urls')),
    #path('ckeditor/',include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path("ckeditor5/", include('django_ckeditor_5.urls'), name="ck_editor_5_upload_file"),
    path('contents/', views.contents),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
$ cat portfolio/models.py
from django.db import models
#from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from django_ckeditor_5.fields import CKEditor5Field
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    progress = models.TextField(verbose_name="Достижение")
    #description = RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name="Описание")
    description = CKEditor5Field(verbose_name="Описание", config_name='extends')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home//Project1/backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home//Project1/backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 413, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/dato/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 454, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/dato/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 519, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/dato/pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 738, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 47, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 731, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home//Project1/backend/Project1/urls.py", line 11, in <module>
    path("ckeditor5/", include('django_ckeditor_5.urls'), name="ck_editor_5_upload_file"),
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 39, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_ckeditor_5/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_ckeditor_5/views.py", line 48, in <module>
    storage = get_storage_class()
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django_ckeditor_5/views.py", line 29, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(storage_setting)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "/home//pyenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'path_to_storage'


It's pretty obvious path_to_storage.CustomStorage isn't meant to literally be there. You're supposed to configure that to the path of the storage backend you want to use...

Your errors are here:
CKEDITOR_5_CUSTOM_CSS = 'path_to.css' # optional
CKEDITOR_5_FILE_STORAGE = "path_to_storage.CustomStorage" # optional

If you are not using custom CSS and custom Storage class, you shouldn't define these settings.
Either remove them or comment them out:
# CKEDITOR_5_CUSTOM_CSS = 'path_to.css' # optional
# CKEDITOR_5_FILE_STORAGE = "path_to_storage.CustomStorage" # optional


If you want to use custom CSS and custom storage class:
You should create your css file, place it somewhere within your project directory and write path to it:
CKEDITOR_5_CUSTOM_CSS = 'path_to.css'
replace 'path_to.css' with the correct path.
It is similar idea for custom storage class as well.
